# PHP and MySQL not working when transferred online

Tags: php, mysql

I created a phonebook in HTML, PHP and MySQL. All it does is:

- Add Contact
- Delete Contact
- View all contacts

This works perfectly on my local machine within XAMPP. I transferred everything online to my godaddy hosting account. I had to create new connection details to the database and everything worked well except...

now -> Delete Contact is not working. It outputs 'Contact deleted' but nothing is deleted.

Here is the source code below, can someone assist?

```
<?php

require 'database/connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['firstname'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE first_name='{$name}'";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if($result) {
        print 'Contact deleted';
    } else {
        print 'Error: '. $db->errno;
    }
} else {
    print 'Nothing is set';
}


$db->close();

print '<br>';
print '<form action="index.html" action="GET">';
print '<input type="submit" value="Main Screen">';
print '</form>';


?>
```

Comment: http://www.farazislam.com/phonebook/ <- the app can be found here

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?  I don't see that in your code.

Comment: By the looks of it, you are mixing MySQL APIs. One of the signs is `$db->query` - `mysql_real_escape_string` which should be its `mysqli_` equivalent. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: You're also using a GET method and trying to access a POST array. However, there are no elements to support those in your form.

Comment: Then you have `form action="index.html"` unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP, that won't work. It needs a `.php` extension. Besides what Robert said about the DB connection, your question is unclear and I have voted to close as such.

Comment: thanks Fred, the mixing of mysqli apis did the trick

Comment: @jimbo123 You're welcome. Since someone else posted an answer and didn't address the real issue, I should post one and you can accept it in order to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing MySQL APIs usng `mysql_real_escape_string()` which should be its `mysqli_` equivalent `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

- Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

While passing the DB connection parameter to it:

Procedural style

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$name);
```

or as Object oriented style:

```
$name = $db->real_escape_string($name);
```

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Object oriented style

> string mysqli::escape_string ( string $escapestr )

Procedural style

> string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE first_name='{$name}'";
```

maybe if you write it like:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE first_name='$name'";
```

without the "{}" because the query is looking for something like : "{some people}" including the "{}"

you are getting the "Contact deleted" because is deleted the term where found {some people} or it delete 0 items and it's a valid query with 0 rows affected.

Sorry for the bad english... :( i hope the answer can help you...

Comment: Do go over their code again, *very carefully*, including comments left under their question. Those will give you a better indication.